# How can I setup and debug "instructure canvas lms" on my desktop using IDE

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, canvas-lms

I want to do application development (i.e adding new features) of "instructure canvas lms" on top of existing open source code https://github.com/instructure/canvas-lms" avalible. For this I need a IDE with debugging and development ability. Also I need procedure to setup the avalible code on my desktop using the IDE.

Comment: What is your questions?

Comment: please read the guide for how to ask a question on stackoverflow http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I want to work with canvas Lms code from my desktop? What are the steps to should I follow to do it.

Comment: Meaning I want to setup local environment for canvas lms code on my desktop. And from there i can do my development. So, is there any document which has all the steps to do this.

Comment: I was able to run and debug ruby on rails project on desktop,  but I was unable to setup canvas lms code on desktop. I need steps to setup this.

Answer (score 1):

RubyMine is a good IDE for working with Canvas LMS. I know that some of the Instructure engineers have used RubyMine when developing Canvas. Most of the other engineers use a text editor and the command line to do everything. And, of course, a browser is involved at some point along the way (usually Google Chrome).

As for setting up Canvas LMS to run on your desktop, I would point you at the Canvas LMS Quick Start Guide:
https://github.com/instructure/canvas-lms/wiki/Quick-Start

Comment: Thanks Mark, I was able to do this on my local system by following Quick-start. Also I was able to open the source code in Ruby mine. But I was unable to run this code from Ruby mine like a local application for debugging.

Comment: @Vinay glad I could help. Hope it goes well.